# Hibernate transaction advice

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate so I need some advice/direction on doing Transactions.

I have a DAO like

```
public class MyDao extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IMyDao {

 @Override
 public Foo getFoo(int id) {

  return (Foo)getHibernateTemplate().load(Foo.class, id);

 }
}
```

With this setup (using HibernateDaoSupport), will Hibernate/Spring handle transactions for me? Some of the examples I see say yes, others show using

```
Transaction tx = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
```

to get a Transaction in every DAO method.

Right now I'm assuming my minimal DAO is correct but I want to do a "larger" transaction that includes a couple of Hibernate calls in one method. Would I use the manual Transaction method there? Do I have to use it everywhere? Thanks.

Comment: Belongs on stackoverflow?

Comment: Yup, the question here is clearly not "does it make my ass look fat", but "does it work" (see this meta answer : http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-is-this-site-different-from-stackoverflow/141#141 )

Comment: I was torn on whether this belongs on SO or not since what I have might be right, I just want to know if it's the right way of doing it or not. I'm fine with moving it though.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should never handle transactions in dao code, as you never know where the transaction boundary is. You should let whoever wants to control the transactions control them.

Code that starts and commits a transaction in every dao method is likely to be problematic.

Btw: not very keen at all on 'dao' but as you use it, so will i.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally introduce spring and their hibernate support into your application then you can use there hibernate transaction manager and define transactions in the xml file and then forget about them in the actual code

Comment: I actually have Spring set up and I thought using the HibernateDaoSupport would handle transactions automatically. I'll look into any needed xml changes, thanks.